# Action every x ms, while keeping UI responsive and avoiding multithreading

Tags: .net, events, user-interface, c++-cli

I have a Class Library in C++/Cli with a class `Entity`. Positions of Entities can be changed with `Jump(destination)` (inside Entity-class).

Besides an immediate position change with `Jump(destination)` I need to implement movements with `Move(destination)`. All the points of a Movement are stored in a `Trajectory`-class and I am currently implementing a Movement as a series of Jumps to these points with a certain delay:

```
for(int i = 0; i < trajectory->NumberOfSteps; i++)
{
    // perform one step
    destination = trajectory->Steps[i];
    receivingEntity->Jump(destination);

    // wait
    System::Threading::Thread::Sleep(timePerStep));
}
```

I call `Move()` from a Windows Forms C# Application. My current implementation obviously lets my UI (which is in the same Thread) freeze during the execution of the Motion.

I am looking for a way to keep my UI responsive during the Movement to be able to do things like hit a cancel-button to stop the movement. 
An idea that I had was to do something like "after each step, respond to any event in the event queue (like CancelButtonClicked)". But how do I do this in .net?

```
for(int i = 0; i < trajectory->NumberOfSteps; i++)
{
    // perform one step
    destination = trajectory->Steps[i];
    receivingEntity->Jump(destination);

    ProcessEventQueue()      // How can I do this?

    // wait
    System::Threading::Thread::Sleep(timePerStep));
}
```

Any solution for my idea, or better ideas?

I realize I could do this with another Thread, but if possible I whould like to avoid this.

best regards
richn

Comment: Why do you want to avoid multithreading when that is the obvious solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi Venemo, I want to avoid it because I'm already behind schedule and I'm afraid to run into new problems when starting with multithreading now. But if you can propose an easy solution with multithreading I whould be glad to here it, too.

Comment: Yes, I can give you an easy solution which uses multithreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a `WinForms` app, you can call `Application.DoEvents`.  This will of course open you up to problems of reentrancy, [as described in the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.90).aspx).

An alternative, probably better, would be to use a [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx).

Start it ticking every n milliseconds, do a Jump on each tick, and stop it when you've completed your trajectory or the user has cancelled.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for the response.
My post wasn't correct about my application structure, I corrected it now. The `Move()` takes place in the Class Library, but I will try publishing an event there, catching it in the UI and do `Application.DoEvents` there.

Will look into your timer solution, too!

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a Timer class as well.

But you could cause paint messages to repeat creating a message loop. My WinForms is a bit rusty, but calling Invalidate and then trapping the paint message/event should be enough. You could then track the elapsed time via a timer or by a DateTime subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use multithreading.

- Do what you're doing now (action, then sleep) on a separate thread
- The caveat is that you can only update the GUI from one thread at a time, so when you want to update the GUI from the other thread, you will have to use a Dispatcher.

Alternatively, you could use a Timer, or you could use the Timer on a separate thread.

Comment: Thanks Venemo. Can you help me out me a little code how to use a Dispatcher? Sorry I don't have any experience with this :(